# Setup IIS to require client certificate and to use anonymous authentication

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate, certificate, wcf

Setup IIS to require client certificate and to use anonymous authentication

I have a WCF web service for our customers to use. I want to protect this using client certificates. I will also use the client certificate to identify the customer.

I've made the identification part work, but I cannot make make the IIS require client certificates.

If I set the IIS to accept client certificates, the communication works and I can get the client identity using:

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

But I can also access the site without a client certificate. I'm not sure if those without can do anything else than read the WSDL, but I don't want anyone without a trusted certificate to be able to get any information at all.

If I set the IIS to require client certificate, my test client who should have access gets the error:

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.

I want to allow access only to those who have a client certificate trusted by the server. Anyone else shall be rejected.

Server WCF configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <clientCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" />
          </clientCertificate>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="64343ee2c8338518e78ba698f3936dc92c90db57" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="DefaultBinding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="WebService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding" contract="WebService.IService" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client WCF configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
        <clientCredentials>
          <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="d084c91a8f81878cd4dd991bbab348235f0fd1a3" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" />
          </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://host/WebService/Service.svc"
      behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
      contract="WebService.IService" name="WSHttpBinding_IService">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: Sorry, changed the tag now. It's IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

Ok we have done the same as you. We worked the other way around. We first secured IIS with the client & server certificate. We did this on IIS Express (still in development while I'm posting this). We allowed in IIS express `applicationhost.config` to overwrite specific parts of the web.config. I.e.: `<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`

**Server side Config :**

```
<sytem.serviceModel>
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ClientCert">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
<!--We have a custom service behavior for claim based security -->
        <behavior name="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyNamespace.AdamAuthorizationManager, MyAssembly">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="MyNamespace.AdamAuthorizationPolicy, MyAssembly" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="YourServerCertificateNameWithoutCN=" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
</behaviors>
<services>
      <service name="MyNamespace.OrderService" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
        <endpoint address="https://iisurl/OrderService.svc/ClientCert" contract="wsHttpCertificateBehavior.IOrderService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientCert">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
</sytem.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<security>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication defaultLogonDomain="YourDomain" enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="true">
          <oneToOneMappings>
            <add enabled="true" certificate="Base64HashOfTheCertificate" userName="YourUserName" password="YourPassword" />
          </oneToOneMappings>
        </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <add users="*" accessType="Allow" />
      </authorization>
      <!--Require SSL *AND* require a client certificate -->
      <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
    </security>
</system.WebServer>
```

**On the client:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ClientCertificate">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>

            <clientCertificate findValue="YourClientCertificateNameWithoutCN=" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>

      <endpoint name="ClientCertificate" address="https://iisurl/OrderService.svc/ClientCert" contract="MyNamespace.IOrderService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ClientCertificate" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What helped us a lot was enable Tracing, Logging in the service and the custom authorization policy and the IIS Trace Logs.

We have `iisurl` mapped to 127.0.0.1 in our host file, so we have trusted certifcates. For the iisClientCertificationMapping check [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/configuring-one-to-one-client-certificate-mappings) out.

Don't know if your ssl setup is correct. We have a powershell script for that.
Some parts of it:

Generating the root certificate (powershell)

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{ . "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\makecert.exe" -n "CN=YourRootCA" -r -sv YourRootCA.pvk YourRootCA.cer}


    $certFile = get-childitem $exPath | where {$_.FullName -match "GlobalVisionServicesRootCA.cer"} 
    if ($certFile -ne $NULL) { 
        echo "Discovered the YourRootCA.cer in the same folder as this script, installing it in the LocalMachine\Root certificate store.." 
        $cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($certFile.FullName)
        $rootStore = new-object system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509Store 'Root','LocalMachine'
        $rootStore.Open('ReadWrite')
        $rootStore.Add($cert) 
        $rootStore.Close() 
    }
```

**Generating the server certificate (command line):**

```
makecert.exe  -sk YourDevSrvCert -iv YourRootCA.pvk -n "CN=iisurl" -ic YourRootCA.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe yourservercertificate.cer
```

**Generating the server client (command line):**

```
makecert.exe  -sk ClientDevSrvCert -iv YourRootCA.pvk -n "CN=iisurl" -ic GlobalVisionServicesRootCA.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe iisurl.cer
```

**Binding the certificates to IIS (command line, XP specific):**

```
httpcfg.exe delete ssl -i "0.0.0.0:443"
httpcfg.exe" delete urlacl url="https://iisurl:443/"

httpcfg.exe set urlacl url="https://iisurl:443/" user=Everyone
httpcfg.exe" set ssl -i "0.0.0.0:443" -h ThumpPrint
```

change the ThumpPrint to the ThumpPrint of the certificate with subject name iisurl. 
I recommend you fully automate this with powershell, we have this to, so we can develop on multiple machines. But i can't past all of it here.

I hope this helps you. With this config, if you browse over https to the url iisurl/OrderService It asks you for a client certificate. (In IE)

You can also watch this log:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\Logfiles\HTTPERR